# React with Typescript and React Router(v6)- Form's event.preventDefault() - seems to not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am having this weird issue when I press the button the submit refreshes the page and attaches to the browsers URL parameters. Seems that `preventDefault()` not getting called.

The function that triggers `onSubmit` is this one:

```
const handleLogin = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    console.log("triggered?")
    e.preventDefault()
  ...some api calls
}
```

At first when I press the button (`input[submit]`) seems that this function is not getting called at all as it gets refreshed. But after this first call it attaches to the URL the form input fields and their values (which is quite bad because it exposes f.ex password to the URL).

the jsx of form looks like this:

```
    <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
    ...input elements
    ...
    <div className={'form-group'}>
        <input className="form-control"
            value={"Login"}
            name="login" type="submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

**EDIT:**

So i've noticed that this issue happens because of react-router (v6);

```
 <Routes>
 <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="ui"} />
                    <Route path="ui">
                        <Route index element={getRedirect()}/>
                        <Route path="login" element={<AuthPage/>}/>
                    </Route>

                </Routes>
```

Because the moment the page loads react router makes "redirection" to /ui/ - `localhost:port/ui/`

And thats why on first click `e.preventDefault()` or `e.stopPagination()`  doesnt'work . But if i refresh or go straight to `localhost:port/ui/` instead of just `localhost:port` . The form will work as it should. Honestly i couldn't find a good solution for this :\

Currently i added something like this for dev env (in prod BE should redirect to /ui/ ) .

```
if (!process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
if (!window.location.href.includes("/ui/")) {
    window.location.href = window.location.href + "ui/"
}
```

But this looks very dodgy to me.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't stuff tags into it.

Comment: In case you have a problem with the form in the future, add `method="post"` so you are not making a GET.

Comment: So have you verified that the handleLogin is being called?

Comment: On first press its not handleLogin seems that its not getting called (hence i suspect the refresh happens) . On second click it is fine and i think because it adds params to the url after the first click thats why second click seems to work.
 I tried also to add the suggested method="post" but this one for some reason it gives me error "Cannot POST /ui/login" . I am using react router v6 if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making some mistake here is the totally working example that's work perfectly fine.

```
const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(value);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login" />
    </form>
  );
};

export default App;
```